# Invalid value type: String for Integer

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

The following code

```
public List<Map<String,String>> getPhoneData() {
    List<Map<String, String>> mapp = new List<Map<String, String>>();
    Map<String, Integer> temp
         = new Map<String, Integer>{'type' => 'Profile Value', 'count' => 1};
    return mapp;
}
```

is giving me

```
Compile Error: Invalid value type: String for Integer
```

at line 3

I want to create `Map` with one value `String` and other `Integer`. How to do that?

Comment: The error explains what is wrong, your Map is <String, Integer> and you are passing it {String => String}.  Pass it {String => Integer} instead.

Comment: @EricLeschinski: The point was `type` is `String`. Check my question now

Comment: Don't change the nature of the question after others answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes from around the numbers like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> temp = new Map<String, Integer>{'type' => 123, 'count' => 1};
```

**EDIT:**
As you changed your question completely, the best way of achieving this would be:

```
public List<Map<String,String>> getPhoneData() {
    List<Map<String, String>> mapp = new List<Map<String, String>>();
    Map<String, String> temp = new Map<String, String>{'type' => 'Profile Value', 'count' => '1'};
    return mapp;
}
```

Comment: I didn't just changed value of `type` to show its actually a string

Comment: You changed the Map from `<String, Integer>` to `<String, String>` and `'type' => '123'` to `'type' => 'profile value'`. This changes the question and the solution. Check my updated answer for a solution.

Comment: my whole point of asking this question is because `type` is `String` and `count` is an `Integer`. If I were to set values in this kind. How would I go about it?

Comment: Not. It's impossible. You can't have a Map with as key/value a String AND an Integer at the same time.

Comment: it is `{String=>String,String=>Integer}`

Comment: Yeah, and that's exactly the problem. You can only define a map as <String, String> OR as <String, Integer>. Not as <String, String OR Integer>. You can assign the map as <String, Object> if you want to, but that's just plain ugly.